# Parse error Register or login mistake after mediawiki new installation

Tags: php

I have a fresh mediawiki 1.29.1 installation on godaddy server, PHP5.6. The process was fine. The only thing is that I cannot register new user or login. When I click login I get something like

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or
>   ';' in
>   /home/content/.../html/wiki/includes/specialpage/LoginSignupSpecialPage.php
>   on line 473".

I checked the last several lines, it looks like "

```
    $helper = new LoginHelper( $this->getContext() );
    $helper->showReturnToPage( $type, $returnTo, $returnToQuery, $stickHTTPS );
}

/**
 * Replace some globals to make sure the fact that the user has just been logged in is
 * reflected in the current request.
 * @param User $user
 */
protected function setSessionUserForCurrentRequest() {
    global $wgUs
```

. I try to change PHP.ini file but nothing happened. What can I do then?

Comment: Yeah, if those are the last lines of the file, it's *incomplete.*

Comment: But how can I fix that? Because it was a complete new installation and I did not touch anything on it.

Comment: Where did that file come from? Do you have the complete file somewhere?

Comment: It is from "webroot / wiki / includes / specialpage / LoginSignupSpecialPage.php", I get access from the webserver directly. That's not the complete file but just the last several lines.

Comment: Did you copy those files there? Then check where you copied them from and whether you have the complete file somewhere. Or is that some sort of GoDaddy one-click wiki setup? Then contact GoDaddy support.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, it's solved! I checked the original file and the existing file, found it is not complete, something wrong during ftp uploading...